Align a dropdown submenu with its parent heading
I'm building a Dropdown Menu and I've got stuck with the CSS when trying to align the Sub-Menu-1 so that its centred on the main menu heading.
See this image

Ive gone round in circles and the only way I can see to align it is to add a negative Margin to my .ul-sub-menu-1

This change dosnt feel like its the best way to achieve what i want and that i may hit problems down the line, So I thought it best to ask for some help here :-)


root {
    --clr-primary-400: #f44336;
    --clr-accent-100: #ffffff;
    --clr-accent-900: #000000;
    --font-family-primary: "helvetica";
    --font-family-secondary: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
}




/* Remove Some Defaults */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*font: inherit;*/
    font-family: "helvetica";
}

/* Set Core Root Defaults */
html:focus-within {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Set Core Body Defaults */
body {
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    
}

/* Make Images Easier to Work With */
img,
picture,
svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}


/* Header/Nav Section */

.container[data-type="headercontainer"] {
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 1140px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25),#999393),url(images/hero-photo/a-world-at-war-cover-d-1040-l85.webp);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin: auto;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
    position: relative;
    container-type: inline-size;
}
nav {
    /*background-color: palevioletred;*/
    display: flex;
    padding: 1% 1%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
/* Logo */
nav .logo {
        width: 175px;
    }


.nav-menu-links {
    flex: 1;
    /*text-align: right;*/
    background-color: pink;
}

nav ul {
    /*background-color: deepskyblue;*/
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
    
}
    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
    }

nav a {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
    /*text-align:justify;*/
    /*padding: 0 30px;*/
    list-style: none;
}
nav .a-main-menu-item, .a-main-menu-item-with-submenu {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    /*list-style: none;*/
}


/* Main Menu Item Hover Effects */
nav ul .li-main-menu-item::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f44336;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
nav ul .li-main-menu-item:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Main Menu Item With Submenu Hover Effects */
nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f44336;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Hide Sub-Menu-1 being displayed until Hovered on */
.sub-menu-1 {
    display: none;
}


/* SUB MENU 1 CONFIG */


/*.sub-menu-1 {

}*/

.ul-sub-menu-1 {
    /*width: auto;*/
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    position: fixed;
    width:fit-content;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    white-space: nowrap;
/*  overflow:hidden;*/
    background-color:deepskyblue;
    margin-left:-50px;

}

.li-sub-menu-1-item {
/*  display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;*/
    padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: fit-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.a-sub-menu-1-item {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    /*text-align: left;*/
    list-style: none;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*color: #fff;*/
}

    nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f44336;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}



/*nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 ul {
        margin: 10px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        text-align: left;
    }

    nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li {
        padding: 10px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
        width: fit-content;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative
    }*/

        /*/*nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>World-War-2.org | World War 2 Timelines | 1939-1945</title>
    <meta name="description" content="World-War-2.org - A World at War - A compilation of complete World War 2 Timelines split into Campaigns which detail every event, day by day from 1939 through to 1945.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="world war 2, world war two, world war II, world war 2 timeline, world war two timeline, world war II timeline, world war 2 campaign, world war two campaign, world war II campaign, world war, world, war, timeline, campaign, 2, two, II, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testindex-style.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-media-mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-media-tablet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-media-desktop.css">-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alumni+Sans+Pinstripe:ital@0;1&family=Alumni+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header Section Start -->
    
    
<section class="header">
        <div class="container" data-type="headercontainer">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo/world-war-2-logo.webp" alt="World-War-2.org Logo" title="World-War-2.org"> </a>
                <div class="nav-menu-links" id="navmenulinks">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="index.html">A World at War</a></li>
                        <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="#">The Road to War</a></li>
                        <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
                            <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Eastern Europe</a>
                            <div class="sub-menu-1">
                                <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                                    <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Invasion of Poland</a></li>
                                    <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Winter War</a></li>
                                    <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Barbarossa</a></li>
                                    <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Typhoon</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu"><a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Western Europe</a></li>
                        <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu"><a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Italy and the Balkans</a></li>
                        <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu"><a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">North Africa</a></li>
                        <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu"><a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Battle of the Atlantic</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>



so many things.. display, positioning but only setting the .ul-sub-menu-1
to
margin-left:-50px;
seemed to help.
Pretty stuck now

remove margin-left:-50px; and position fixed. Use position: relative for the parent li and then position:absolute with left:0 for the child ul

left:50% and position: absolute would seem more appropriate.

Many thanks @mehdi for you help. This resolved my issue. I tried both the left:0; and the left:50% suggested by Pauline_D 's with Left 0 working better for me in this instance.
Many thanks
Garreth

I think "negative Margin using" enought for the desktop view. Make sure the dropdown parent's position is relative.
